# bash - extract specific value from file

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cat

I have a file that looks like this:

```
odule(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
$MaxMessageSize 65536
#RSYSLOG_ForwardFormat template is used to enable millisecond-accuracy
$ActionForwardDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_ForwardFormat
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="5140")

mail.info stop

# This is rule for filtering apache logs
:msg, regex, ".*DHCP.*" stop
:msg, regex, ".*HTTP/1.1\" 200 [0-9-]* \"-\" \"ClusterListener/1.0\".*" stop

global(
  workDirectory="/var/lib/rsyslog"   # Directory where queue files will be stored
)
```

I want to extract the value of `port` (which is 5140) and store it in an environment variable.

I have tried using variations of awk, grep, and cat commands to try and achieve this but none seem to give me the desired output.

For example, `sed -n 's/port=\(.*\)/\1/p' < file.conf` gives the following:

```
input(type="imudp" "5140")
```

Which is not what I want. I simply want to store `5140` into an environment variable.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 5):

Since you tagged it, and we already have a `sed` and a `grep` way, here's the awk way ;)

```
awk -F'[ "]' '/port=/{ print $5 }' file.conf
```

Or to have it in a variable `myvar`:

```
myvar=$(awk -F'[ "]' '/port=/{ print $5 }' file.conf)
```

Answer (score 3):

Would you please try the following:

```
export port=$(sed -nE 's/.*port="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' file.txt)
```

then the environment variable `port` will be assigned to `5140`.

Comment: Thanks for this, this seems to work locally anyways. When I try to include this in a Dockerfile, the env var doesn't seem to be set:

Comment: Step 35/39 : RUN export PORT=$(sed -nE 's/.*port="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' /etc/rsyslog.d/0_base.conf)
 ---> Running in a8adecc3889d


Step 37/39 : RUN echo "$PORT"
 ---> Running in 8c7f4e79b6c4

(blank line here)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The lifetime of `environment variable` is limited
within current shell (current process) and the child processes only. I'm not
familiar with `Dockerfile` but it looks the 2nd run does not inherit
the environment variables set in the 1st run. Please take a look of
[BASH script to set environment variables not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53177/bash-script-to-set-environment-variables-not-working).

Answer (score 2):

Does your `grep` support `perlregex`?

```
grep -oP '^input\(.*port="\K\d+' infile
```

Output:

```
5140
```

Answer (score 2):

You are capturing and not matching the `"` before and after `port=` so they will be there after replacing.

If you want to get the capture group value only, you have to match all before and after the group value to not have it in the replacement.

If the port can only be 1 or more digits, you can make it a bit more specific `[[:digit:]]\+`

```
sed -n 's/.*port="\([[:digit:]]\+\)".*/\1/p' < file.conf
```

Output

```
5140
```

---

If you want to make it a bit more specific:

```
sed -n 's/^input([^()]*port="\([[:digit:]]\+\)").*/\1/p' < file.conf
```

The pattern matches

- `^input(` match `input(` at the start of the string
- `[^()]*` Optionally match any character except `(` or `)`
- `port="` Match literally
- `\([[:digit:]]\+\)` Capture 1+ digits in **group 1**
- `")` Match `")`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line